# Wordpress menu items no longer displaying current page styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The CSS styles active or hover state menu items on the site I'm working on no longer display as required, apart from one (kitchens).

If you hover over **Kitchens**, or that page is active it highlights blue, however none of the other link styles are working.

The **Kitchens** menu li item has the "blue" class applied, code is below.

```
<li id="menu-item-48" class="blue menu-item menu-item-type-post_type             menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-48">    
<a href="http://wanderingcooks.com.au/commercial-kitchen-space/">Kitchens</a>
</li>
```

I'm stumped about how to add the other correct classes to the menu items. There are styles defined, each should be a different color and I believe it's not working since the pages were renamed. There's an area in the Wordpress admin to apply the styles but that's no good either. 
I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "kitchen" link has a class "blue" added to its `li` element, but none of the others have the "colour" classes:

```
<ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">    
    <li id="menu-item-7923" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7923">
        <a href="http://wanderingcooks.com.au/thank-truck-its-thursday/">What’s On</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-48" class="blue menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48">
        <a href="http://wanderingcooks.com.au/commercial-kitchen-space/">Kitchens</a>
    </li>
    [...]
```

The blue hover effect is only added to links that are in a 'li' element with the blue class:

```
.primary_nav_menu .menu-item.blue a:hover, .primary_nav_menu .menu-item.blue a:active {
    color: #25aae1;
}
```

To fix this, you need to add `blue` (or the other "colour" classes) to all the list elements.

**Add custom classes to your menu items**

1. In the admin, go to Appearance > Menus
2. Click on the "Screen Options" tab in the top right corner - this will reveal a settings panel
3. Under "Show advanced menu properties", check the "CSS Classes" checkbox
4. Now look at the Menu Structure where your menu items are. Click on the down arrow to the right of the grey block for a menu item you'd like to change.
5. Underneath the "*Navigation Label*" you will now have a textbox labelled "*CSS Classes (optional)*". You can add any custom classes here - just enter the class name exactly, without a preceding dot, e.g. `blue`.
6. Save your menu, and when you now view the page source in the browser, the `<li>`s for your menu items should include your colour classes in the class list.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I'm not sure on how to do. I want to add a different color class to each 'li'

So the first menu item I would like to add red class, next teal class and so on.

I'm not sure how to edit the code of the menu to do this.

Comment: @Droid How do you add the "blue" class at the moment? Also when you say there's an area in the admin to apply the styles, what area do you mean?

Comment: @Droid "*In the backend there is a*"... ? Looks like you just gave up at the end of your comment there :) Was there more to that sentence? Its the area in the backend that your trying to use that I'm wondering about. Where is that exactly, what did you try putting in there and what was the result? i.e. did the styles get added to the code but didn't change when you looked at it in the browser, did nothing change at all, or did something unexpected happen?

Comment: I've just taken over administering the site, the blue class was already added and apparently the other styles stopped working when the parent menu items where changed. 

In the Wordpress backend there is a Theme Settings section which allows me to select a top level page and apply a color to it. This seems to just color of the little call out boxes to the right only though. 

I apologise I realise this is a vague query, appreciate the help. Cheers

Comment: only the call out boxes on the page seem to change color. The menu items aren't changing - no code, no style, nuthin. :)

Comment: @Droid No problem, I'm just trying to get a picture of what you have and what you're already tried so I can try to help. Are you logging in as the admin? I have a suggestion I think will work but you'd need full access to the menus area in the backend and for it not to be altered by any plugins such as Adminimize. I'll update my for you to try it.

Comment: @Droid I've updated my answer - try that and let me know how you get on.